# Finding unique elements in cells of pandas DF and expanding DF to include columns with the names of those unique elements

Tags: python, pandas, split

I have a DF that looks like this:

[image]

I want to create a new DF, let's say instrumentsDF,  in some sort of vectorized form so I get something like this:

```
0       Piano  Guitar Viola
0       0      0      1
1       0      1      0
2       1      0      1
3       0      1      0
4       1      1      1
```

I don't know how many unique favored_instruments I have in the cells, which means I don't know how many columns I will have in the new DF.

My code thus far is this, but can't think of how to expand it to output what I need:

```
crunk = lambda x: pd.Series([i for i in reversed(x.split(','))])
vector = compDf['favored_instrument'].apply(crunk)
print vector
```

Which produces this:

```
        0          1       2
0       Piano      NaN     NaN
1       Piano      NaN     NaN
2       Piano      NaN     NaN
3       Guitar     Piano   NaN
4       Piano      NaN     NaN
```

I could try to iterate over each row of the DF, split the value with ',', and add to a python list, but that approach could be slow. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think worries about performance are secondary.  First, make the dataframe you called `vector` by taking advantage of `.str.split` with `expand=True`:

```
>>> df
    favoured_instrument
0                 Piano
1                 Viola
2          Viola, Piano
3                Guitar
4  Piano, Guitar, Viola
>>> d2 = df["favoured_instrument"].str.split("\s*,\s*", expand=True)
>>> d2
        0       1      2
0   Piano    None   None
1   Viola    None   None
2   Viola   Piano   None
3  Guitar    None   None
4   Piano  Guitar  Viola
```

And then we can pivot this in many ways.  Using `get_dummies`, for example:

```
>>> pd.get_dummies(d2.stack()).groupby(level=0).sum()
   Guitar  Piano  Viola
0       0      1      0
1       0      0      1
2       0      1      1
3       1      0      0
4       1      1      1
```

Comment: Great answer DSM! Thank you very much. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Pandas has the `get_dummies` function:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> data = pd.DataFrame({'instrument': ['Piano', 'Piano', 'Guitar', 'Viola', 'Viola', 'Guitar']})

>>> pd.get_dummies(data['instrument'])
   instrument_Guitar  instrument_Piano  instrument_Viola
0                  0                 1                 0
1                  0                 1                 0
2                  1                 0                 0
3                  0                 0                 1
4                  0                 0                 1
5                  1                 0                 0
```

Comment: Thank you, but your solution assumes that I know all the unique instruments in the DF

Answer (score 0):

`sklearn.preprocessing.LabelBinarizer` may be very usefull

brief example:

```
from sklearn import preprocessing
lb= preprocessing.LabelBinarizer()
lb.fit_transform(['Piano', 'Piano', 'Guitar', 'Viola', 'Viola', 'Guitar'])
```

result:

```
array([[0, 1, 0],
       [0, 1, 0],
       [1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 1],
       [1, 0, 0]])
```

`lb.classes_` - columns names

Comment: Thank you Alexey. Your solution would work if I knew all the unique_instruments. They are all bundled in different combinations with no specific order, but comma separated.